# Establishing a few properties of the lower and upper Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble in establishing a few properties of *lower* and *upper Lebesgue integral* which are defined as 
$$\underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx=\sup_{h \leq f ~a.e.; ~h:simple}Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}h(x)dx$$ 
$$\overline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx=\inf_{h \geq f ~a.e.; ~h:simple}Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}h(x)dx$$

The properties that I have to establish are as follows:

**(I)** *Horizontal truncation:* As $n \to \infty$, show that $\underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}min(f(x),n)dx$ converges to $\underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$.

**(II)** *Vertical truncation:* As $n \to \infty$, show that $\underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)1_{\lvert x \rvert \leq n}dx$ converges to $\underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$.

Do the *horizontal* and *vertical truncation* properties hold if the *lower Lebesgue integral* is replaced by *upper Lebesgue integral*?

**(III)** *Reflection:* If $f+g$ is *simple function* that is bounded with finite measure support (i.e. it is *absolutely integrable*), then $Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\{f(x)+g(x)\}dx=\underline \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx+\overline \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)dx$

**My problems:**

In **(I)**, if $f$ is bounded then *horizontal truncation* is trivial. By monotonicity, it is easy to deduce that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \underline \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}min(f(x),n)dx \leq \underline\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$ in all cases. But I cannot show the other inequality for the non-trivial case (i.e. when the function is *not* bounded).

In **(II)**, I have to use the result $m(E \cap \{x:\lvert x \rvert \leq n\}) \to m(E)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any measurable set $E$. But I cannot connect *Lebesgue measure* to the definition of *lower Lebesgue integral* (and obviously to the definition of *upper Lebesgue integral* to check whether the property holds for *upper Lebesgue integral*).

In **(III)**, I don't really have a clue. The *lower* and *upper Lebesgue integral* in the *R.H.S.* are giving me two opposite inequalities from which no conclusion can be drawn.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (I): by definition of the lower integral, you can find a simple function $h \le f$ whose integral is close to the lower integral of $f$.  Simple functions are  bounded, hence for all sufficiently large $n$, you have $h \le \min(f,n)$ as well.  So you should be able to conclude something about $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \underline{\int} \min(f, n)$.

Hint for (II): The connection is that Lebesgue measure appears in the definition of the simple integral.  As before, choose a simple $h$ whose integral is close to that of $f$.  How does the vertical truncation of $h$ compare to that of $f$?  Now note that the vertical truncation of $h$ is also a simple function, and you should be able to say something about what happens to its simple integral when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get your points. Can you give me a hint for Part-III *(Reflection property)* as well? Also I've got no idea why they call it *Reflection* property, there must be some intuition behind it.

Answer (score 2):

For (3),

For $\forall 0\le f'\le f$, $f'$ is a simple function, since $f+g$ is simple , we observe that $g':=f+g-f'$ is a simple function such that $g'\ge g$. Obviously we have 
\begin{align}
&\text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f(x)+g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x=\text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f'(x)+g'(x)\ \mathrm {d}x\\&=\text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f'(x)\mathrm {d}x+\text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}g'(x)\mathrm {d}x\ge \text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f'(x)\mathrm {d}x+\overline {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}g(x)\mathrm {d}x
\end{align} 
Taking the supremum we soon have 
\begin{align}
\text {Simp} {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f(x)+g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x\ge \underline {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}f(x)\mathrm {d}x+\overline {\int_{\mathbb {R}^d}}g(x)\mathrm {d}x
\end{align} 
The other direction can be obtained similarly. Thus we get the result.